# What is the proper way to access DB model's save method from within route handler function?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have noticed when one creates a project using Express.js, the route handler functions are now separated from the main 'app.js' file.  They are now placed in './routes/index.js'. Given this situation, how does one now save a record to the database (in this case using MongoDB accessed via Mongoose).

Traditionally one would have had the route handler function in 'app.js', for example:

```js
//Create document 
app.post('/documents.:format?', function(req, res) {
  var d = new Document(req.body);
  d.user_id = req.currentUser.id;
  d.save(function() {
    switch (req.params.format) {
      case 'json':
        var data = d.toObject();
        // TODO: Backbone requires 'id', but can I alias it?
        data.id = data._id;
        res.send(data);
      break;

      default:
        req.flash('info', 'Document created');
        res.redirect('/documents');
    }
  });
});
```

Under the new "layout" such call would be changed to something like the following (in 'app.js' file):

```js
app.post('/documents.:format?', routes.add_documents);
```

With all the actual processing occurring in the file './route/index.js':

```js
exports.add_documents = function(req, res){
  // Processing goes here!
};
```

My question is how can one incorporate the original route handler function into this new add_documents function above?  In particular, how can one access the database schema model (e.g. create new instance of 'Document') so that I can access the database save method?

Full contents of 'app.js' is follows:

```js
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models = require('./models')
  , Document;

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://localhost/namecards');
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

models.defineModels(mongoose, function() {
  app.Document = Document = mongoose.model('Document');
  db = mongoose.connect(app.set('db-uri'));
})

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/add', routes.add_form);

app.post('/add', routes.add_document);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

Content of 'models.js'

```js
function defineModels(mongoose, fn) {
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
      ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

  /**
   * Model: Document
   */
  Document = new Schema({
    'surname': String,
    'given_name': String,
    'org': String,
    'phone': String
  });

  mongoose.model('Document', Document);

  fn();
}

exports.defineModels = defineModels;
```

Content of './routes/index.js'

```js
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Documents' });
};

/*
 * GET add contact page.
 */
exports.add_form = function(req, res){
  res.render('add', { title: 'Add Document' });
};

/*
 * POST add contact page.
 */
exports.add_document = function(req, res){
  // Save data to DB using mongoose.
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method that appears to work, which doesn't involve a huge number of changes to the code originally generated by Express.  All you have to do is import mongoose into the file containing the route handler functions a.k.a. the controllers, and then load the relevant model in the routing function (see exports.addProcess below).

Here is the modified contents of './routes/index.js'

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('underscore');


/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Documents' });
};

/*
 * POST add contact page.
 */
exports.addProcess = function(req, res){
  var Document = mongoose.model('Document');
  var document= new Document();
  document.surname = req.body.surname;
  document.given_name = req.body.given_name;
  document.org = req.body.org;
  document.phone = req.body.phone;
  document.save(function(err) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually call that a controller to follow MVC.

I would import my model/schema into the controller

Following is how I do MVC in node/express

```
//controller

module.exports = function (app, models) {
  var ctrl = {
    add_documents: function(req, res) {
         var document = new models.Document();
         document.something = something;
         document.save();
         res.end("Saved");
    }
  return crtl;
}

//sample model
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
var Document = new mongoose.Schema({
    field: value
});
var model = mongoose.model('Document', Document);
return model;
 }


//model loader
module.exports = function(app, mongoose) {
mongooseTypes = require("mongoose-types"); 
mongooseTypes.loadTypes(mongoose);
var obj = {
    Document: require('./models/document.js')(mongoose)
}
return obj;
}

//app.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var models = require('./models')(app, mongoose);
var routes = require('./routes')(app, models); 

//routes
module.exports = function(app, models) {
    var DocumentController = require("./controllers/documents")(app, models);
    app.post('/documents:.format', DocumentController.add_documents);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Makes sense to pass the model into the 'Controller'.  I am a little confused on how to implement your solution here. Where does the controller code go?

Comment: //routes
module.exports = function(app, models) {
    var DocumentController = require("./controllers/documents")(app, models);
    app.post('/documents:.format', DocumentController.add_documents);
}

Comment: ^ it is loaded by the routes.

Comment: I'm afraid i am having trouble converting the above example into discrete code.  How does one divide this code up? Which sections of code should go into which files? Do I need to completely modify 'app.js'? Or is there a way to apply the logic of the proposed solution within the structure already created by Express (controllers are currently stored in './routes/index.js')? I have modified original question to reveal more of the apps overall structure.